# Getting the thread ID from a thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

In C# when debugging threads for example, you can see each thread's ID.

I couldn't find a way to get that same thread, programmatically. I could not even get the ID of the current thread (in the properties of the `Thread.currentThread`).

So, I wonder how does Visual Studio get the IDs of the threads, and is there a way to get the handle of the thread with id `2345`, for example?

Answer (score 496, accepted):

[`GetThreadId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms683233(VS.85).aspx) returns the ID of a given native thread. There are ways to make it work with managed threads, I'm sure, all you need to find is the thread handle and pass it to that function.

For managed threads, use [`System.Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.environment.currentmanagedthreadid).

Older SDK options included below exist, however the preferred usage is `System.Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId`.

- [`GetCurrentThreadId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms683183(VS.85).aspx) returns the ID of the current thread. `GetCurrentThreadId` has been deprecated as of .NET 2.0.
- [`Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.thread.managedthreadid.aspx) returns the unique identifier for the current managed thread, the same as `System.Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId` however, `System.Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId` is preferred ([CA1840](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1840)).

Comment: Well If there's a managed answer without dllimport, i'll have to accept his answer. But thanks a lot for the effort. And i might actually use your answer since it is reliable.

Comment: This is closer to the real thing (read the native side) since managed threads can be translated to fibers running on one native thread, and since you mentioned the vs debugger, this is probably what you want.

Comment: Since I found this, typed it, and then was told it was Deprecated, the current way to do this is Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId

Comment: ManagedThreadId is not a robust approach to identify threads as the ManagedThreadId property id's get reused by your app. So it is not a reliable identifier for threads in some scenarios and you will experience the exception : "An item with the same key has already been added." at line...
Give the thread a unique name when you create it.

Comment: There's some very bad advice going around on this post. A few people are recommending to use "ManagedThreadId" to identify a thread. I edited the post to remove the recommendation - what very few have pointed out is that there are different types of thread ids. Managed thread IDs are not the same thing as unmanaged thread ids, and if people were to copy & paste that code some very subtle synchronization bugs could occur. The documentation on MSDN for the Thread class is very clear about this. View the remarks at the class level.

Comment: You don't synchronize on ID's though, you use synchronization primitives like mutexes. This is only for debugging purposes.

Comment: I would like to post this comment to notice that `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` won't work at least when using in a `SetWindowsHookEx`. Instead we have to get the thread id from the native win32 function `GetCurrentThreadId()`.

Comment: It's almost 2023 now, and VS is telling me to use `Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId` instead.

Answer (score 96):

> In C# when debugging threads for example, you can see each thread's ID.

This will be the Ids of the managed threads.  `ManagedThreadId` is a member of `Thread` so you can get the Id from any [Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.threading.thread.aspx) object.  This will get you the current [ManagedThreadID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.managedthreadid.aspx):

```
Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
```

To get an OS thread by its OS thread ID *(not ManagedThreadID)*, you can try a bit of linq.

```
int unmanagedId = 2345;
ProcessThread myThread = (from ProcessThread entry in Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads
   where entry.Id == unmanagedId 
   select entry).First();
```

It seems there is no way to enumerate the managed threads and no relation between ProcessThread and Thread, so getting a managed thread by its Id is a tough one.

For more details on Managed vs Unmanaged threading, see [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/74169f59.aspx).

Comment: Why didn't anyone else come up with this simple answer?

Comment: This does not work. GetCurrentProcess().Threads returns a ProcessThreadCollection, which is not convertible to Threads. I don't see an easy fix.

Comment: @ mafutrct, updated answer.  That property should really be called .ProcessThreads! Thanks.

Comment: Recommend this post be rewritten to make it clearer that the two thread ids are different. If someone fails to read the last sentence, they'll just plug ManagedThreadId and try to map it against ProcessThread.Id, creating havok.

Comment: I've added a link to a helpful MSDN acticle highlighting the difference.  However, the question was related to getting the thread ID for debugging (which in this case is the ManagedThreadID).  I don't think cluttering the answer with details of the difference between OS and managed threads is useful.

Answer (score 50):

You can use the deprecated [`AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getcurrentthreadid.aspx) to get the ID of the currently running thread. This method uses a PInvoke to the Win32 API method `GetCurrentThreadID`, and will return the Windows thread ID.

This method is marked as deprecated because the .NET Thread object does not correspond to a single Windows thread, and as such there is no stable ID which can be returned by Windows for a given .NET thread.

See configurator's answer for more reasons why this is the case.

Comment: CAUTION With .Net Core 2.2, note that AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId (I invoked via MethodInfo as Obsolete) returns the managed thread ID (useless for matching Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads collection.

Answer (score 36):

To get the OS ID use:

```
AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId()
```

Comment: GetHashCode isn't necessarily unique! and should not use it to identify a thread.

Comment: You could use AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId() if you want the OS thread ID, but multiple .NET threads could in theory share the same OS thread. Thread.GetHashCode() is guaranteed to return a value that is unique process-wide, which is what you probably want.

Comment: Perhaps 'AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId();' would have been a better answer to this question. Should I answer the question twice? Delete this? Or someone should suggest this, then I will vote them up. :)

Comment: Feels dirty... none of the comments here make sense now.

Comment: The method is marked as deprecated, and with good reason. Please see my answer and configurator's for the fuller picture.

Comment: Well this is the only way to get to the OS Thread ID. And this should be marked as the correct answer.
Even though that i'm not going to rely on this any more.

Comment: "multiple .net threads could in theory share the same OS thread"? I fail to see why any implementation would benefit from this theoretical possibility. Sounds like obfuscation to me.

Comment: `AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId()` is obsolete: `AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId ` has been deprecated because it does not provide a stable Id when managed threads are running on `fibers (aka lightweight threads)`. 
 
To get a stable identifier for a managed thread, use the `ManagedThreadId` property on `Thread`.
 

 
Usage: `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId`

Comment: CAUTION With .Net Core 2.2, note that AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId (I invoked via MethodInfo as Obsolete) returns the managed thread ID (useless for matching Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads collection

Comment: Though `AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId()` function has been deprecated but truly this provides a way to link OS Threads with Managed Threads. What's harm if someone wants to use it solely for debugging?

Answer (score 23):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx):

> An operating-system ThreadId has no
>   fixed relationship to a managed
>   thread, because an unmanaged host can
>   control the relationship between
>   managed and unmanaged threads.
>   Specifically, a sophisticated host can
>   use the CLR Hosting API to schedule
>   many managed threads against the same
>   operating system thread, or to move a
>   managed thread between different
>   operating system threads.

So basically, the `Thread` object does not necessarily correspond to an OS thread - which is why it doesn't have the native ID exposed.

Comment: Debug/Threads window in VS2010 shows "Managed thread ID". How can I get this one?

Comment: Use the ManagedThreadID property http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.managedthreadid.aspx . This isn't the same as the OS thread ID though.

Answer (score 15):

To find the current thread Id use - `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId'.
But in this case you might need the current win32 thread id - use pInvoke to get it with this function:

```
[DllImport("Kernel32", EntryPoint = "GetCurrentThreadId", ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern Int32 GetCurrentWin32ThreadId();
```

First you'll need to save the managed thread id and win32 thread id connection - use a dictionary that maps a win32 id to managed thread.

Then to find a thread by it's id iterate over the process's thread using Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads and find the thread with that id:

```
foreach (ProcessThread thread in Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads)
{
     var managedThread = win32ToManagedThread[thread.id];
     if((managedThread.ManagedThreadId == threadId)
     {
         return managedThread;
     }
}
```

Comment: I believe the OP is asking for the OS ID of the thread, which is not the same as the managed thread ID.

Comment: This code does not work: Process.Threads returns a collection of `ProcessThread` objects, this is not the same as (nor does it inherit) `Thread`: `(thread as Thread)` will return a null reference.

Comment: I've noticed that code code had a few bugs - fixed it try it now

Comment: I ended up using a dictionary that maps a win32 id to a managed thread.

Answer (score 15):

For those about to hack:

```
    public static int GetNativeThreadId(Thread thread)
    {
        var f = typeof(Thread).GetField("DONT_USE_InternalThread",
            BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        var pInternalThread = (IntPtr)f.GetValue(thread);
        var nativeId = Marshal.ReadInt32(pInternalThread, (IntPtr.Size == 8) ? 548 : 348); // found by analyzing the memory
        return nativeId;
    }
```

Answer (score 15):

The offset under Windows 10 is 0x022C (x64-bit-Application) and 0x0160 (x32-bit-Application):

```
public static int GetNativeThreadId(Thread thread)
{
    var f = typeof(Thread).GetField("DONT_USE_InternalThread",
        BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

    var pInternalThread = (IntPtr)f.GetValue(thread);
    var nativeId = Marshal.ReadInt32(pInternalThread, (IntPtr.Size == 8) ? 0x022C : 0x0160); // found by analyzing the memory
    return nativeId;
}
```

Comment: Works on Windows 7 x64 with SP1 as well. Not recommanded though. Only use in temporary testing.

Comment: We do not use it for temporary testing, but for diagnostic purposes in production environments with our iplus-framework (https://iplus-framework.com)

Answer (score 8):

As of July 2022 the VS2022 IDE suggests using `System.Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId` instead of `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId`

Quoting from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1840:

> System.Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId is a compact and efficient replacement of the Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId pattern.

Answer (score 5):

From managed code you have access to instances of the `Thread` type for each managed thread. `Thread` encapsulates the concept of an OS thread and as of the current CLR there's a one-to-one correspondance with managed threads and OS threads. However, this is an implementation detail, that may change in the future.

The ID displayed by Visual Studio is actually the OS thread ID. This is *not* the same as the managed thread ID as suggested by several replies.

The `Thread` type does include a private IntPtr member field called `DONT_USE_InternalThread`, which points to the underlying OS structure. However, as this is really an implementation detail it is not advisable to pursue this IMO. And the name sort of indicates that you shouldn't rely on this.

Comment: To use GetThreadId you'd need the handle - which you get from the DONT_USE field.

Comment: I know, but as I said you can't really count on the fact that managed threads maps directly to OS threads, so I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification, and summurizing the problem.
But now if multiple managed threads can correspond to a single OS thread (As configurator stated - and he's thanked), that means that VS is showing OS threads and not Managed Threads.

Comment: @OhrmaZd: Yes, VS2005/2008 shows OS IDs for managed threads in the Threads window. VS2010B2 actually shows both OS and managed ID per thread.

Comment: @Brian Rasmussen: Now that's an identification for a managed thread! Thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Thread.GetHashCode, which returns the managed thread ID. If you think about the purpose of GetHashCode, this makes good sense -- it needs to be a unique identifier (e.g. key in a dictionary) for the object (the thread).

The [reference source for the Thread class](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/thread.cs) is instructive here. (Granted, a particular .NET implementation *may* not be based on this source code, but for debugging purposes I'll take my chances.)

[GetHashCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx) "provides this hash code for algorithms that need quick checks of object equality," so it is well-suited for checking Thread equality -- for example to assert that a particular method is executing on the thread you wanted it called from.

Comment: Awesome, I just had this 5 year old question open for an hour, came back and saw "1 new answer to this question" :D

Comment: This answer was hinted at in another comment, but was what I ended up using after some further research. Possibly not what the OP wanted. Likely the OP doesn't care anymore. Might be useful to someone else. (And at least based on the reference source, this may be the most efficient way to get the thread ID.)

Comment: well i'm in a different field right now, but back then, we had two IDs for a thread, the id of the native thread, and an id for the managed thread, and one belongs to another one...
Principally, the IDs are intended to identify the threads, GetHashCodes have other utility, and may collide. Framework developers wouldn't have implemented an ID if  we had to use GetHashCode

Comment: Understood, and true, but note that GetHashCode is intended not to collide -- collisions break Dictionary use, for example. Also the implementation of GetHashCode does actually return a cached copy of the managed thread ID, so *might* be faster in performance-critical situations.

Comment: @yoyo Collisions do not break dictionary use.  They are designed to have a low probability of collision, not no collision at all. If you hash a 128bit value to a 64bit value then every hash value will have approximately _2^64_ collisions. The dictionary is designed to have a [fallback algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2975784/158285) when a collision occurs in the rare case it does.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing You are absolutely right, and my previous comment is wrong. Dictionary performance will degrade with hash collisions, but functionality remains correct. My apologies for the misleading comment, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @yoyo One question if `ManagedThreadId` and `GetHashCode()` returns same value then how does it matter which one is used? Please `Therad.GetHashCode()` and `ProcessThread.GetHashCode()` returns totally different values. So one cannot use `GetHashCode()` to relate `ManagedThreads Id` with `OS Thread Id`.

Answer (score 3):

<del>System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name</del>

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
```