# What happens when hash collision happens in Dictionary key?

Tags: c#, hash, collision-detection

I've been coding in c++ and java entirety of my life but on C#, I feel like it's a totally different animal.

In case of hash collision in Dictionary container in c#, what does it do?  or does it even detect the collision?

In case of collisions in similar containers in SDL, some would make a key value section link data to key value section like linked list, or some would attempt to find different hash method.

[Update 10:56 A.M. 6/4/2010]

I am trying to make a counter per user.  And set user # is not defined, it can both increase or decrease.  And I'm expecting the size of data to be over 1000.

So, I want :

- fast Access preferably not O(n), It important that I have close to O(1) due to requirement, I need to make sure I can force log off people before they are able to execute something silly.
- Dynamic growth and shrink.
- unique data.

Hashmap was my solution, and it seems Dictionary is what is similar to hashmap in c#...

Comment: Can you add more information as to why you need to know this?  The `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` is only defined to function correctly in the face of conflicting hashcode values.  Any information about how it does so is an implementation detail and subject to change between releases

Comment: As of .NET 3.5 your best bet might be HashSet<T> (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx). If a hash collision occurs then the object goes in the next available bucket. See reference source (http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs,2d265edc718b158b) for full details, such as "The capacity is always prime; so during resizing, the capacity is chosen as the next prime greater than double the last capacity." Unfortunately no constructor takes a capacity, but you could call TrimExcess once you have populated the set.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

**Hash collisions are correctly handled by `Dictionary<>`** - in that so long as an object implements `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()` correctly, the appropriate instance will be returned from the dictionary.

First, you shouldn't make any assumptions about how `Dictionary<>` works internally - that's an implementation detail that is likely to change over time. Having said that....

**What you should be concerned with is whether the types you are using for keys implement `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()` correctly.** The basic rules are that `GetHashCode()` must return the same value for the lifetime of the object, and that `Equals()` must return true when two instances represent the same object. Unless you override it, `Equals()` uses reference equality - which means it only returns true if two objects are actually the same instance. You may override how `Equals()` works, but then you must ensure that two objects that are 'equal' also produce the same hash code.

**From a performance standpoint, you may also want to provide an implementation of `GetHashCode()` that generates a good spread of values to reduce the frequency of hashcode collision.** The primarily downside of hashcode collisions, is that it reduces the dictionary into a list in terms of performance. Whenever two different object instances yield the same hash code, they are stored in the same internal bucket of the dictionary. The result of this, is that a linear scan must be performed, calling `Equals()` on each instance until a match is found.

Comment: FWIW, you can use Redgate .NET Reflector to look at the actual implementation, but LBushkin is correct, it's likely to change over time, so don't count on it.

Comment: But do you know whether it would double the hashmap capacity in case of collision??  Cause that maybe too expensive for me.

Comment: Looking at the code, it looks like the `.Resize()` function is only called when the entire dictionary is full. The current implementation seems to find the NEXT bucket when a collision happens, but this is just my interpretation of reverse-engineered IL, so make of that what you will.

Comment: @Ankiov: What runtime environment are you with what kind of data loads, that you are concerned about this? Are you on the .NET Compact framework? The implementations may be different than the client version (for instance on Windows Phone there's a slightly different version of the BCL and CLR).

Comment: It be on the just normal .NET framework, not the mobile or any compact ones.  But what worries me is that data size can grow significantly.

@Aren B: thanks much!

Answer (score 21):

According to [this article at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379571(VS.80).aspx), in case of a hash collision the `Dictionary` class converts the bucket into a linked list. The older `HashTable` class, on the other hand, uses rehashing.

Answer (score 15):

I offer an alternative code oriented answer that demonstrates a Dictionary will exhibit exception-free and functionally correct behavior when two items with different keys are added but the keys produce the same hashcode.

On .Net 4.6 the strings "699391" and "1241308" produce the same hashcode. What happens in the following code?

```
myDictionary.Add( "699391", "abc" );
myDictionary.Add( "1241308", "def" );
```

The following code demonstrates that a .Net Dictionary accepts different keys that cause a hash collision. No exception is thrown and dictionary key lookup returns the expected object.

```
var hashes = new Dictionary<int, string>();
var collisions = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; ; ++i)
{
    string st = i.ToString();
    int hash = st.GetHashCode();

    if (hashes.TryGetValue( hash, out string collision ))
    {
        // On .Net 4.6 we find "699391" and "1241308".
        collisions.Add( collision );
        collisions.Add( st );
        break;
    }
    else
        hashes.Add( hash, st );
}
Debug.Assert( collisions[0] != collisions[1], "Check we have produced two different strings" );
Debug.Assert( collisions[0].GetHashCode() == collisions[1].GetHashCode(), "Prove we have different strings producing the same hashcode" );

var newDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
newDictionary.Add( collisions[0], "abc" );
newDictionary.Add( collisions[1], "def" );

Console.Write( "If we get here without an exception being thrown, it demonstrates a dictionary accepts multiple items with different keys that produce the same hash value." );

Debug.Assert( newDictionary[collisions[0]] == "abc" );
Debug.Assert( newDictionary[collisions[1]] == "def" );
```

Answer (score 3):

Check this link for a good explanation: [An Extensive Examination of Data Structures Using C# 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379571%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Basically, .NET generic dictionary chains items with the same hash value.