# GetHashCode() - change item id and then find that item in dictionary - KeyNotFoundException

Tags: c#

Finding items in dictionary is based on hash code. The hash code is based on item id in below code so I shouldn't change item id. But I have done some experiment and I have changed item id and searched it in dictionary but then I have got KeyNotFoundException. Could somebody explain me why?

**After change point1 id, it has 1727699806 hash code, element with index 0 in dictionary has the same hash code: 1727699806 - so why I have KeyNotFoundException?**

```
class Program
{
    public class Point
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return obj is Point point &&
                    Id == point.Id;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return HashCode.Combine(Id);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Point point1 = new Point();
        point1.Id = 5;            

        Point point2 = new Point();
        point2.Id = 20;

        var dictionary = new Dictionary<Point, string>()
        {
            { point1, "Poland" },
            { point2, "Germany" }
        };

        point1.Id = 999; // here I change id
        var point1_hash = point1.GetHashCode(); //1727699806

        var dictionary1_hash = dictionary.ElementAt(0).Key.GetHashCode(); //1727699806
        var dictionary2_hash = dictionary.ElementAt(1).Key.GetHashCode(); //650208270

        string result = dictionary[point1]; //KeyNotFoundException
    }
}
```

After change point1 id, it has 1727699806 hash code, element with index 0 in dictionary has the same hash code: 1727699806 - so why I have KeyNotFoundException?

Comment: So you know that you shouldn't do that and are confused that it leads to problems?

Comment: Because `5 != 999`, even if both have the same hashcode https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975612/what-happens-when-hash-collision-happens-in-dictionary-key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This answer was incorrect, but cannot be deleted for technical reasons. See Progman's answer below, instead.**

Comment: -1, This doesn't explain why the key isn't found even though it's inside the Dictionary. It is even the exact same object so it should find it (and not throw a KeyNotFoundException). The problem is that the key to look for is now in the wrong internal bucket of the `Dictionary` class after changing the `Id` and therefore the hash code.

Comment: @Progman: Good point, I overlooked that part. Can't delete the answer now, though.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the object/key is placed in a so called "bucket" inside the `Dictionary` class. Each entry in a bucket has the same hashcode (simplified, there are some modulo operations involved so there aren't `int.MaxValue` buckets). When you insert or retrieve an object with the key, the `Dictionary` class only needs to look in one bucket because the keys have the same hashcode.

But now you have changed the hashcode of the key object by changing the `Id` property. The key `point1` is now stored in a bucket where it doesn't belong to, but the `Dictionary` class doesn't know about that change. This means:

1. When you use the getter, a different hashcode will be calculate so the `Dictionary` class will look in a different bucket.
2. The `Dictionary` class will not find the key/entry, because it is in the previous selected bucket (a different one).

For that reason, you must not change the object of the `key` to produce a different hashcode, while is it used as a key in a `Dictionary`. See the [documentation of the `Dictionary` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8):

> As long as an object is used as a key in the `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`, it must not change in any way that affects its hash value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the related [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs.html#bcd13bb775d408f1) inside `Dictionary<T>` class:

```
private int FindEntry(TKey key)
{
    if (buckets != null)
    {
        int hashCode = comparer.GetHashCode(key) & 0x7FFFFFFF;
        for (int i = buckets[hashCode % buckets.Length]; i >= 0; i = entries[i].next)
        {
            if (entries[i].hashCode == hashCode && comparer.Equals(entries[i].key, key)) return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

As you can see, searching for a key starts by calculating the hashcode of the searched key. This hashcode determines the bucket that will be searched for a matching entry. Then each entry inside the specified bucket is compared first by the **stored** hashcode, and then by value of the key. So changing the key of an entity stored in a dictionary breaks the key finding algorithm in three different ways.