# Can I use GetHashCode without Equals?

Tags: c#, hash, gethashcode, hash-collision

Maybe I don’t understand something. No, I definitely don’t understand something. There is a custom class with two int type properties. Overriding the GetHashCode method, I want to use both of these properties as the basis for obtaining the hash code. But, since the return type of the GetHashCode method is int, and the two properties in my class have int. It turns out that there will be more combinations of various values ​​of my properties than the int type can accommodate. As a result, in any case, I will have collisions. Right?
In addition, I want to say that I tried several algorithms marked as acceptable answers, from other topics in which, among others, authoritative people such as Jon Skeet offered their options, but still got collisions.

```
    public class Equivalent
    {
        public Equivalent(int a, int b)
        {
            A = a;
            B = b;
        }

        public int A { get; }
        public int B { get; }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            var vals = new[]
            {
                A.GetHashCode(),
                B.GetHashCode()
            };

            var hash1 = (5381 << 16) + 5381;
            var hash2 = hash1;

            var i = 0;
            foreach (var hashCode in vals)
            {
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                    hash1 = ((hash1 << 5) + hash1 + (hash1 >> 27)) ^ hashCode;
                else
                    hash2 = ((hash2 << 5) + hash2 + (hash2 >> 27)) ^ hashCode;

                ++i;
            }

            return hash1 + (hash2 * 1566083941);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{A};{B}";
        }
    }

    public void GetHash()
    {
        var len = 1000000;
        var d = new Dictionary<int, Equivalent>();
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            var eq = new Equivalent(
                _r.Next(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue),
                _r.Next(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue));

            var hash = eq.GetHashCode();
            if (d.TryGetValue(hash, out var saved))
            {
                File.AppendAllText("result2.csv", $"{hash};{saved}\n");
                File.AppendAllText("result2.csv", $"{hash};{eq}\n");
                continue;
            }

            d.Add(hash, eq);
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you add more useful tags so others can find this question easier?

Comment: Is what you aren't asking covered by [What happens when hash collision happens in Dictionary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2975612/1115360)

Comment: Hash codes aren't unique identifiers for objects; two non-equal objects are allowed to have the same hash code. Collisions are definitely to be expected.

Comment: What, exactly, is your question?

Comment: @JimMischel My question is whether the hash code is good for identifying an object. Apparently not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are trying to use `GetHashCode` for something it's not meant for.
Check out [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425142/what-is-hashcode-used-for-is-it-unique) for a bit more context.

I am not entirely sure I understand the intent behind the `if (d.TryGetValue(hash, out var saved))` - I am assuming you want to check if you already saved this particular line into your CSV. If that is indeed the case you might find it easier maintain a HashSet because it basically masks away your `int` key while allowing you to check for uniqueness:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        var eq = new Equivalent(
            _r.Next(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue),
            _r.Next(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue));

        if(!d.Contains(eq))
        {
            //File.AppendAllText("result2.csv", $"{hash};{saved}\n"); // do you need this line?
            File.AppendAllText("result2.csv", $"{eq.GetProperSha1Hash()};{eq}\n");//you will need to implement the method, but there's plenty examples
            d.Add(eq);
            continue;
        }
        Thread.Sleep(1);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. The answer to which you gave a link was useful. I needed the line that you commented out to compare the contents of objects for which the same hash codes were received.
`if (d.TryGetValue(hash, out var saved))` this is probably an attempt to play it safe.
Can I use the Equals method in my example to verify the second step in identifying an object? Well, when will I get two identical hashes.

Comment: I don’t see `Equals` implementation in your example, but yes, this is the prescribed approach: you implement both `Equals` and `GetHashCode` and let `Dictionary´ (or ´HashSet´) do it’s magic. To make life easier I would have a tool like Resharper generate equality members for me.