# windows thread id from managed thread id

Tags: c#

I know the managed thread id of thread (obtained fr.om a locked object)  I also know that this threadis causing a deadlock. Is it possible to identify the windows thread id? is there any utility available for identifying this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#/.NET: How to get the thread id  from a thread?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679243/c-net-how-to-get-the-thread-id-from-a-thread)

Comment: Obtaining such thread ID makes no sense because it is not constant for the same managed thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Threads Window in VS2010 displays both the managed and the native ID.

EDIT in reply to comment: I don't believe the information is available in VS2005/8, but you can get it during debugging by loading SOS through the immediate window.

- To load SOS use the `.load sos` command in the immediate window.
- To get the thread IDs use the `!threads` SOS command. The ID column holds the managed ID for the thread.

Comment: Is it possible to get the same behavior in VS2005 and VS2008?