# Getting the thread ID

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#/.NET: How to get the thread id from a thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679243/c-net-how-to-get-the-thread-id-from-a-thread)

How I can get the same thread ID as I see it in Visual Studio?

I have tried to use `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId`, but I am getting different numbers.

I am getting 35, 38, 39, etc., but in Visual Studio I have 10596, 893, etc...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use GetCurrentThreadId() or ManagedThreadId() to get the thread ID:

```
int threadID = (int)AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId();
int managedThreadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
Console.WriteLine("ThreadId = " + threadID);
Console.WriteLine("ManagedThreadId = " + managedThreadId);
```

Have a look at Stack Overflow question *[Getting the thread ID from a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679243)*.

Comment: `System.AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId()` is obsolete/deprecated.

Comment: Deprecated but if you're trying to map to what you see in the "threads" dropdown in visual studio it's still the way to go

Comment: I wonder what the the alternative to get the ThreadID is now.  I can't find one anywhere.  And don't say ManagedThreadId lol.  The thing is... when Threads Exit... The Output in Visual Studio outputs the threads 'ThreadID', NOT the ManagedThreadId.  So for me the ManagedThreadId was no good as it didn't tell me what I needed to know.  I used the Deprecated method and converted the Int to Hex as Visual Studio Outputs the ThreadId in Hex. 
 `Hex(AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId())`

Answer (score 3):

You can  use WinApi functions [GetCurrentThreadId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683183%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [GetThreadId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683233%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

If you are seeing a different thread ID in your live application as opposed to when you debug in Visual Studio, that is just what you should expect to see, right?

When running in the debugger, you are effectively running the application in the debugger host which will have different threads than just running the application on its own.

Comment: I don't think he was talking about an application running without VS. Wouldn't make any sense...