# Get Thread ID from Window

Tags: c#, winforms, winforms-interop

I need to obtain the Thread Id from a window create in runtime with this code

```
System.Windows.Window MyWindow = new System.Windows.Window();
MyWindow.Show();
```

I'm getting the window handler using

```
IntPtr WindowHandle = (new WindowInteropHelper(MyWindow)).Handle;
```

How can I get the Thread Id from the window or its corresponding handler?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679243/c-net-how-to-get-the-thread-id-from-a-thread?

Comment: I don't doubt you need the thread necessarily, but I am curious why you think you need the thread ID.  I could imagine you don't need it and that there are more appropriate API calls to do what you actually want to do.

Comment: Darkshadw: Not duplicate because I dont have the thread from the new window

Comment: sethcall: I need the thread ID because it's what a 3rd party dll requires ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [GetWindowThreadProcessId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method

According to MSDN

> Retrieves the identifier of the thread that created the specified
>   window and, optionally, the identifier of the process that created the
>   window.

Comment: Is there any way to check if I'm getting the correct ID? Because the 3rd party dll isn't doing whats supposed to do