# How to check whether thread is alive by using thread name in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have a thread name .By using that thread name how i may need to find whether the thread is alive or not.
In Thread Name I have a combination of app_num and Id which helps to refer me when new thread starts.So I need to give condition that if thread is already alive for same App_num and Queue_Id then it skips starting another new thread  as it already exists

Thanks in advance

Comment: The fact you want to do this suggests you are solving the 'wrong' problem.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat In Thread Name I have a combination of app_num and Id which helps to refer me when new thread starts.So I need to give condition that if thread is already alive for same App_num and Queue_Id then it skips starting another new thread  as it already exists

Comment: @Chow.Net - and immediately after your check completes, the thread which was *just* about to exit now completely exits. By the time you *act* on the result of your check, there is no such thread running. That (or other such races) is probably what Mitch was trying to hint to you. It's a broken idea.

Answer (score 1):

From your provided details I am expecting that you are in need of [Thread.IsAlive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isalive.aspx) property.

Don't forget to look at the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679243/getting-the-thread-id-from-a-thread) thread, it will help you to get threads from a process (See badbod99's solution)

Hope it helps!