# C# Serilog Thread Id does not correspond with thread id in process explorer

Tags: c#, .net, serilog, process-explorer

I use an enriched serilog configuration that logs the thread id. This results in logging the thread id in a 2 digit number:

[image]

Now I want to check a high CPU issue and which thread is causing it. For this I open process explorer, but there, the threads id's are shown as 4 digit keys:

[image]

Why are they different? Is it possible to log the id in 4 digit way, or show the 2 digit thread id in process explorer? Or can the somehow be translated?

Comment: Please show use your code/config for Serilog.

Comment: If Serilog reports the managed thread id then they will not coincide with the actual thread id that the operating system deals with. Thread ids in the operating system are 32-bit integers.

Comment: I used this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1679346/1435647 and log OS thread id explicitly. Ids may be not 100% reliable.