# SetWindowsHookEx always returning 0 with error code 87 (ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER) in .net 8 WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, user32, setwindowshookex

In my application I would like to register a hook per `SetWindowsHookEx`. Basically I would like to execute some code, whenever a mouse event occurs.

The method however, always returns 0. The last error code per `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error` is 87 (ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER), I'm not sure which parameter is faulty.

I have set a breakpoint in the HookProc, but it is not beeing hit. I've also tried this in a test project and it didn't work there either. I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```cs
// SetWindowsHookEx import:
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern int SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hInstance, int threadId);

// WH_MOUSE:
public const int WH_MOUSE = 7;

// _hookProc is of the following type:
public delegate int HookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

// SetWindowsHookEx call:
int hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE, _hookProc,(IntPtr)null,Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId);
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.setlasterror?view=net-7.0

Comment: Thanks, now at least an error code is shown :)
I will add this to the post in an edit.

Comment: `Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId` is wrong, that's internal to .NET. Just use `0` for "all threads".

Comment: Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId is the problem, that's a .NET number and not an identifier for an OS thread.  You can't use @Charlieface advice either, WH_MOUSE requires a DLL that can be injected into other processes, such a DLL cannot contain managed code.  [Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679243/getting-the-thread-id-from-a-thread).

Comment: Do keep in mind that this is a bazooka to kill a mosquito, getting mouse events to fire in a WPF app should not require military hardware.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for your help!
 I replaced `Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId` with an imported `GetCurrentThreadId();` from kernel32.dll.
Now it seems to work :)
I tried `AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId()` but that did not seem to work for me.